# Retrieving contacts from different mail accounts?

Tags: php

I'm designing a site and I want to extract all contacts from a mail account, such as Yahoo, GMail, MSN, etc. Please help me how I can achieve this.

Comment: wow, not only 0% accept, 13 questions asked... could be reasonable if he asked 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[Open Inviter](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4927.html)**.

Comment: Yes you can use that for the purpose, check that out.

Comment: Open Inviter only working for gmail account it not work for other mail account.how can i solve these problem?

Comment: @Sushant: It supports 
<br />
* AOL
* GMail
* GMX.net
* Windows Live (Hotmail)
* Katamail
* Lycos
* Mail.com
* Mail.ru
* Rambler.ru
* Rediff
* Yahoo!
* Yandex
* Facebook
* Hi5
* LinkedIn
* MySpace
* Orkut
* Twitter